# PlayFramework Activator Error

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I created my first Play app ang get the error using  "run" command:

**Cause**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.OrderedDownstreamMessageEvent
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55$$anon$2.loadClass(PlayCommands.scala:535)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:123)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:272)
at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
at play.core.server.NettyServer$.mainDev(NettyServer.scala:271)
at play.core.server.NettyServer.mainDev(NettyServer.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55.apply(PlayCommands.scala:575)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53$$anonfun$55.apply(PlayCommands.scala:507)
at scala.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:533)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53.apply(PlayCommands.scala:507)
at sbt.PlayCommands$$anonfun$53.apply(PlayCommands.scala:487)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$sbt$Command$$apply1$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Command.scala:72)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:90)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
at sbt.State$$anon$2.process(State.scala:171)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$next$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:71)
at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:64)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:53)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:50)
at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:50)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:33)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:17)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:13)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:26)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
```

Any ideas what is that?

**Details**:

java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)

play-version:2.1.2

sbt-version:0.12.4

activator-version:1.0

Comment: Add more details: which JVM, activator version, Play version, etc

Comment: Added the details below the logs.

Comment: Why are you creating a new app using Play 2.1.2 instead of an newer version (right now 2.5.1 is the latest version)?

Comment: Source? I suggest you updating Java, SBT and Activator (Play). From Java you need version 8 with the latest Play (2.4 onwards).